# What's the difference between num=+10 and num+=10?

Tags: java, assignment-operator

I am new to java, so while experimenting (which is, as you know, the best way to learn), I tried the following code:

```
public class wHilE{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int num = 10;
      while(num<=100){
        System.out.println("while countdown = "+ num);
        num=+10;
      }
   }
}
```

It results is an infinite loop printing `while countdown = 10`, but when I change `num=+10` to `num+=10` I get the desired result.

Why is it so?

Comment: `num =+ 10 <=> num = +10 <=> num = 10`. `num += 10 <=> num = num + 10`.

Answer (score 10):

`num=+10` is equivalent to `num=10`. That's why the loop never ended.

`num+=10` is equivalent to `num=num+10`, which gives you the desired behavior.

Answer (score 7):

The `+=` is a compound assignment; the `=+` is a normal assignment, followed by a plus sign, which is optional for positive numbers:

```
 x += 10;
 ^ ^^ ^^
 |  |  |
var |  val
compound assignment
```

vs.

```
 x = +10;
 ^ ^ ^^^
 | |  |
var| val
assignment
```

The first operation adds ten to `x`; the second operation assigns 10 to `x` regardless of its prior value.

Answer (score 3):

`num += 10` means `num = num + 10`
It will assign num + 10 value to num.

Whereas `num=+10` means `num = +10` which means +10 value will be stored in num.
+10 here means positive 10.